# Colors changing to black when changing from .BMP to .ICO in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, icons, bitmaps

I would like to create a custom icon for a shortcut (in Windows 10).  Several sites like [this one](https://www.wikihow.com/Create-and-Use-Custom-Icons) suggest first creating a bitmap, and then saving that .bmp with a .ico extension.  I follow the instructions and there doesn't seem to be any problems.

But when I look at the file I've created, it appears black.  Other colors are wrong, too.  In the picture, the top file is the .bmp; the bottom is the .ico file.  The original picture was 32 pixels x 32 pixels; I saved as a 24-bit bitmap.  (I also tried as a 16-color and a 256-color bitmap, but the problem persisted.)

**Why are the colors changing when I save as .ico, and how do I prevent this?**

[image]

Comment: After further fiddling, I discovered that white and several shades of gray all turn into black when the .ico is saved.  When I open the file up again in Paint, though, the colors are correct.